# innerHTML is not working for some tags like button or custom tags

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Problem in interpolation when I assign some html tags(like button) or custom tag by angular interpolation then its not showing

**In component.html file**

`<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>`

**In component.ts file**

`html = "<h1>Header</h1> <button>Button</button>"`

Not working in angular
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j5gsb4?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

It's working in pure html/js
https://plnkr.co/edit/3PWexJjKbOEe50egKjqJ?p=preview

Comment: In the linked question see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089093/217408 that demonstrates the sanitizer.

Answer (score 9):

`innerHTML` is not a attribute exposed as a property of HTML Element.

```
<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>
```

So this will not work.

You can use `@ViewChild` to access DOM Element

**app.component.html**

```
<div #someVar></div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('someVar') el:ElementRef;

constructor() {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = "some html";
}
```

Comment: why it is working for `<p><h1> tags` ?

Comment: @AkshayGarg it wont work for `p` or `h1` tags. What you are doing is `<h1>Header</h1>` and it completely different than `<h1 innerHTML="somthing"></h1>`. Earlier one is a string which you are setting in DOM. So it will work just normally.

Comment: no no my question is when i am assign `html = <h1>Header</h1><button>Button</button>` then h1 is working properly but button not working

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `innerHTML` **is**  exposed as a property of HTML Element (even your code `nativeElement.innerHTML = ...` demonstrated that). Suggesting direct DOM access instead of Angular view binding is against what the Angular team suggests.

Answer (score 4):

By default Angular is sanitizing potential unsafe content.
You can tell Angular to trust your content

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){
    this.html = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<h1>Header</h1><button>Button</button>");
  }
  html;
}
```

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rgvsyg)

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089093/217408