# Angular innerHTML property not working while try to render button control

Tags: html, css, angular, innerhtml

I have created angular application.in here, i want to inject some content using [innerHTML] property like below

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  public bar = 'bars';
  foo = `<div>`+this.bar+`
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
`;
}
```

I have used this in html file like below

```html
<div [innerHTML]="foo"></div>
```

But I just simply return only div element. button control is not getting rendered.

I have created a stackb sample for your reference. please provide any idea how to do it

> sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ena2xj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Reference - [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Comment: Better Use renderer2 service: https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/

Comment: @Chellappan, Hi Bro, why not we use @viewChild??

Comment: Better way to manipulte DOM in angular is using Render2 service.

Comment: @Chellappan, Okay bro, using Render2 service might be also a good solution i hope..

Comment: hi @Chellappan, is there any guidelines available to use render 2 service

Comment: Hi @kumaresan_sd Check this:alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2

Comment: thanks @Chellappan, but i don't need this

Comment: HI @ManirajfromKarur, i have one more scenario, how to achieve this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phv9ry?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: i have created one component and i want to render it using this innerHTML property

Comment: reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289132/can-not-use-another-component-in-innerhtml-property-binding

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you should use **DomSanitizer**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
        constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

   name = 'Angular';
  public bar = 'bars';
  foo = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml( `<div>`+this.bar+`
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
`);
}
```

Comment: HI @devraj, Thanks for your quick reply. it is working fine

Comment: I have one more doubt. is is possible to create another component and use here

Comment: that is not possible.

Comment: What about adding attribute binding to the foo? @Devrajs

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to @ViewChild,

Change your `ts` file like this,

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('someVar') el:ElementRef;
  name = 'Angular';
  public bar = 'bar';
  ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = `<div>`+this.bar+`
  </div><button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>`;
}
}
```

**Working Stackblitz** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnk9ft

Comment: @kumaresan_sd, Why don't you want to use ```ViewChild``` ??

Comment: i don't want to take element reference because i have to inject this in multiple elements.

Comment: @kumaresan_sd, Okay this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879407/innerhtml-is-not-working-for-some-tags-like-button-or-custom-tags propose both solutions, and another answer deals with first solution of it.. Hope you got better solution for your problem..